# Scraping variable names and values from html definition lists using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm looking to extract some data from a definition list in some html code in R. So far I've done the following;

```
url <- "myurl"
doc <- htmlParse(url)
```

and then I (think I) want to use `xpathSApply` to extract the list data; however I keep returning an error... I'm new to the concept of webscraping and HTML, so I'm not entirely sure how the function goes about locating the data to scrape.

How do I find the `xpath` to pass to `xpathSApply`?

an example url would be http://opencorporates.com/companies/gb/06309283

and I would want to scrape the data regarding company name, number, address, directors etc. into one observation per query.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You'll get better answers if you make your question reproducible. Here, that might mean a URL. Also, I changed your question to better reflect what I think your intent might be.  Please edit if that was not what you meant to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has an amazing plugin called FireBug, and an extension to that called FirePath.  Using that, you can right click on any element on a web page and click "Inspect" .  That will show you the XPath to be passed to `xpathSApply`.

Comment: Cheers, unfortunately I haven't got the option of working with firefox (just IE9) I'll edit the question to include a url to make it reproducible

Comment: Ugh.  Other people may have other software suggestions, but FirePath was a pretty dramatic improvement over trying to come up with xpaths from raw XML or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use Firebug there's a nifty bookmarklet called [SelectorGadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/) that does much the same thing and should work in IE9

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the syntax that I was in need of was the '//node[@class="myclass"]' for use in the xpathSAppply function. Cheers all